# Updating react hook takes a very long time

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to optimize react application. The application works fine on small dataset but with large datasets (500-1000 records) it slows down. By using react profiler extension I have narrowed down the problem to one function more specifically when updating the react hooks.

```
const [repeatPattern, setRepeatPattern] = useState<any | null>({ id: 0, text: 'Does not repeat' });
```

The Function body contains:

```
setRepeatPattern({ id: 2, text: 'Daily' });
```

The setRepeatPattern takes roughly 2 seconds to execute. P.S I have not use repeatPattern in any useEffect.

Comment: From the code you share it is impossible to tell what the problem is - setting a new state will cause any number of renders / side-effects. Consider looking into and get to use the react profiler, part of the react dev tools to get a pretty concrete idea of where the time is being burned.

Comment: Is there a component you're rendering for each record?

Comment: No for just 1 record.